# Change text color when clicking button in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting back into learning Javascript and am running into trouble with changing text color when clicking a button.

A lot of the other questions have referenced changing the color of the button itself, and the code I have does not seem to have an error.

```
<body>
<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>Exciting stuff! This is my first web page.</p>
<button id= “color”>Change color!</button>
<script>
document.getElementById('color').onclick = changeColor; var currentColor = “red”;
function changeColor() { 
        if(currentColor == “red”){ 
    document.body.style.color = “green”;
    currentColor = “green”;
        } else {
        document.body.style.color = “red”;
        currentColor = “red”;
        } 
            return currentColor; 
    }
</script>
</body>
```

However, the line

```
document.getElementById('color').onclick = changeColor; var currentColor = “red”;
```

generates an error saying that it is an illegal token. Initially, I thought the issue had to do with not putting the code in a form. The instructional video's demonstration seemed to work fine, but I keep getting this error. Can anyone provide an idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your code works perfectly but you use `incorrect` syntax. Change `“` to `"` 
quotation marks.

Also, you do not need to use `return` statement inside the function, which represents `onclick` event handler.

```html
<body>
<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>Exciting stuff! This is my first web page.</p>
<button id= "color">Change color!</button>
<script>
document.getElementById('color').onclick = changeColor; 
var currentColor = "red";
function changeColor() { 
        if(currentColor == "red"){ 
           document.body.style.color = "green";
           currentColor = "green";
        } else {
           document.body.style.color = "red";
           currentColor = "red";
        } 
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: @Louis?, don't foget to accept answer in order to help other people.